# Протоколирование действий пользователя

Tags: c#, winforms, логирование

Доброго времени суток. Имеется учебно-исследовательский комплекс, опишу в паре слов, несколько пользователей (обучаемые и инструктор), Инструктор создает сценарий обучения, и собственно тестовые модули для обучаемых, на примере данных с предприятия. 
Каким образом можно протоколировать все действия обучаемых во время изучения комплекса, прохождение тестов и юзание кнопок, и т.д. 
Что-то по типу документации/логирования, чтобы инструктор мог потом открыть и просмотреть эту информацию.

В читаемой где-то документации наткнулся на `Log4Net`, который можно подключить через NuGet, но так и не понял, что это за фрукт, и как его использовать, буду рад практическому примеру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша задача состоит из двух, на самом деле: 
1) подключение любого логгера
2) логирование действий пользователя

Подключить логгер не составляет труда https://habrahabr.ru/post/310770/

Логирование действий пользователя также довольно тривиально:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _logger.Log.Info("Button clicked");
}
```